# My apartment complex's hot tub has been broken for multiple months now. I wouldn't have lived here if not for the hot tub

Tags: washington, lease

Over the summer (about 4-5 months ago), the hot tub in my apartment complex broke. I contacted the complex owners, and they said it would take a couple of weeks to fix. I've contacted them multiple times since then, and they keep telling me it will be "just another week or two". I've done this exclusively over the phone.

If this complex did not have a hot tub, I likely wouldn't have chosen to live here - it was a pretty major factor in why I chose this apartment complex. My complex owners are known for having terrible maintenance (and they have lived up to that rumor). I live in a small town so this is well-known among my local community.

I'm going to be moving out when my lease is up (in a few more months), but I don't want to move before then. Is there any way I can get some money back for the months I've lived here without the hot tub, or money back off my future rent payment? They are unwilling to negotiate anything out of goodwill (I've already tried contacting them to work this out nicely).

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but they advertise their hot tub and pool room pretty heavily. Their website currently has it listed under "amenities" with no indication that it's broken.

Comment: What does your lease say regarding the hot tub?

Comment: It says that we are entitled to use the amenities provided, but doesn't specify the amenities (although it is listed on their website) and doesn't provide any kind of guarantee that they'll be available.